# How to get whole row's size in df using scala

Tags: dataframe, scala

DataFrame has multiple columns. I need add a new column for the whole row size which means I need add all columns size together. Is there a simple way to do it efficiently? Thanks

Here is the sample:

```
val DataFrame = Seq(("Alice", "He is girl"), ("Bob", "She is girl"), ("Ben", null)).toDF("name","string") 
display(DataFrame)
```

I want to add a column to df that it can sum length of each column. In this sample only two columns, but actually I have hundred columns in the df.

Comment: Can you provide a sample DataFrame and an example of what you have tried? I don't know if you are asking for the number of columns in each row, or some kind of calculation based on the contents of the columns.

Comment: Here is the sample:
val DataFrame = Seq(("Alice", "He is girl"), ("Bob", "She is girl"), ("Ben", null)).toDF("name","string")
display(DataFrame)

I want to add a column to df that it can sum length of each column. In this sample only two columns, but actually I have hundred columns in the df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val df = Seq(("Alice", "He is girl"), 
   ("Bob", "She is girl"), ("Ben", null)).toDF("name","string")

scala> df.show
+-----+-----------+
| name|     string|
+-----+-----------+
|Alice| He is girl|
|  Bob|She is girl|
|  Ben|       null|
+-----+-----------+
```

Get rid of null values:

```
val dfNoNull = df.na.fill("")

scala> dfNoNull.show
+-----+-----------+
| name|     string|
+-----+-----------+
|Alice| He is girl|
|  Bob|She is girl|
|  Ben|           |
+-----+-----------+
```

Create list of columns with applied `length` function to each of them:

```
val cols = dfNoNull.columns.map(x => length(col(x)))
```

Select data based on these columns/expressions:

```
val dfColCounts = dfNoNull.select(cols:_*)

scala> dfColCounts.show
+------------+--------------+
|length(name)|length(string)|
+------------+--------------+
|           5|            10|
|           3|            11|
|           3|             0|
+------------+--------------+
```

Get these new colum names:

```
val countCols = dfColCounts.columns.map(x => col(x))
```

Apply reduce to sum up all column values which are ints by now:

```
val dfPerRowCounts = dfColCounts
   .withColumn("countPerRow", countCols.reduce(_ + _))
   .select("countPerRow")
```

Result:

```
dfPerRowCounts.show

scala> dfPerRowCounts.show
+-----------+
|countPerRow|
+-----------+
|         15|
|         14|
|          3|
+-----------+
```